# How to remove HTML line breaks<br />?

Tags: html, r, text, data-cleaning, topic-modeling

I have a dataset of web scraped reviews and unfortunately they contain a lot of the `<br \>` tags, so after I clean the data (remove stopwords etc.), a lot of single "br" remain in the dataset.
I would like to remove these line breaks as well as some random alphanumeric characters (f.e. b00oex3) which make no sense in the text. So after cleaning this is an Example:

```
 product b001e5dxao br train chocolate chai mix 12 ounce bags br br
```

I would like to turn this into

```
product train chocolate chai mix ounce bags.
```

I've tried

```
gsub("(<br />)"," ",text)
```

but it returns the following error

> Error in gsub(., "(
> )", " ", text) :
> assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634
> In addition: Warning message:
> In gsub(., "(
> )", " ", text) :
> argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: I don't get that error when I run your code.  The error message appears to have a linebreak in it; maybe the pattern is being modified before being run?

Comment: I applied it to a whole dataset in a string of commands. Maybe this code only works for one sentence and not a whole frame

Comment: The code you have shown us does not cause this error. You need to produce and post a [mcve].

Comment: It looks like, the regex is too long. `rex <- paste(do.call(paste0, expand.grid(letters, letters, letters)), collapse = "|"); gsub(rex, "", "abc")` will give your first error message. The second comes from that your regex vector is longer than 1 e.g. `gsub(letters, "", "abc")`

Answer (score 0):

You could try working with `read_html()` and `html_elements()` from the rvest package to parse the html and avoid ending up with html markup in the first place.